# extract data from master data using python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe that is created every hour and it includes junk data as well. I have a column with some categorical values. I want to create separate data frames for some specific values in that column. Example:

```
data(main data)

data1 = data.loc[data.column == 'A']
data2 = data.loc[data.column == 'B']
data3 = data.loc[data.column == 'C']
```

But in some cases, the main data won't have value 'A' or 'B' or 'C'. Nonetheless, I want to extract these data if available.
My problem is if any of the data is not available, the code will crash. How can I avoid this?

Note: The subset name of data should always be the same (ex: data1 is always for 'A', data2 for 'B', data3 for 'C'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
data1 = None
if 'A' in data.columns:
    data1 = data.loc[data.column == 'A']
...
if data1:
    # Processing of data1 if available
    ...
```

Or:

```
try:
    data1 = data.loc[data.column == 'A']
except:
    data1 = None
...
if data1:
    # Processing of data1 if available
    ...
```